# Bash ANSI C quoting not correctly quoting newlines

Tags: bash, quoting

ANSI C Quoting in bash is supposed to read strings the same way C(or python with single quotes) would.

```
printf $'"Hello, World!\\n"'

#expected output (no newline, the slash is escaped)
"Hello, World!\n"

#actual output (one newline)
"Hello, World!
"
```

But it seems to not be working properly. Is that a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `printf` wrong. You have provided the string where a format string is expected, and `printf` interprets `\n` accordingly. Use a proper format string and provide the ANSI-C-quoted string as an argument:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $'"Hello, World!\\n"'
"Hello, World!\n"
```

Or, to show more clearly where the argument goes in the format string:

```
$ printf '|%s|\n' $'"Hello, World!\\n"'
|"Hello, World!\n"|
```

Comment: `echo -e` *also* interprets escape sequences. To print a string verbatim, use `printf %s`

Comment: funny I missed that, `-e` option is explicitly for interpreting escape sequences.

Comment: If you have a few dozen minutes to spare, have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/70524